# SQL Server Xml query with undeclared prefix

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, xpath, xml-namespaces

I have a variable in SQL Server 2008 that contains a part of a XML column and I am having trouble querying it. The XML *can* contain a prefix "ns0" or not. I want to retrieve [from] from the xml. The query I tried was this:

```
DECLARE @Params XML
SET @Params = '<filter>
                      <ns0:from>2016-09-19</ns0:from>
                      <ns0:to>2017-01-01<ns0:to>
               </filter>';
SELECT @Params.value('(/*:filter/*:from)[1]', 'Varchar(max)') AS [from]
```

I don't have a XML header to declare any namespace. When I try to execute this, I got this error:

```
 XML parsing: line 1, character 10, undeclared prefix
```

But when I try this, everything works fine:

```
SET @Params = '<filter>
                    <from>2016-09-19<from>
                    <to>2017-01-01<to>
               </filter>
SELECT @Params.value('(/*:filter/*:from)[1]', 'Varchar(max)') AS [from]
```

How can I retrieve [from] using an XPath query given the above xml example with a prefix or without prefix?

Comment: The first example is failing at the point the string is parsed into XML - the fragment is not valid XML if the namespace isn't declared. You'll either have to add a namespace declaration, or remove the element namespaces.

Comment: (side point, but you should probably consider casting `[from]` to date (or `datetime`) datatype, rather than `varchar(max`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is invalid in two ways:

1. It is not allowed to have a namespace prefix without a corresponding namespace declaration.
2. Your **closing** tags do not include the `/` everywhere...

This is an ugly hack, but you might try this:

```
DECLARE @Params XML
SET @Params = REPLACE('<filter>
                      <ns0:from>2016-09-19</ns0:from>
                      <ns0:to>2017-01-01</ns0:to>
               </filter>','ns0:','');
SELECT @Params.value('(/*:filter/*:from)[1]', 'date') AS [from];
```

If you do not know all namespace prefixes in advance this will get really tricky...